# How can I change the network adapter of a vm using a cli in esxi?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere

I want to change the network adapter of a guest virtual machine using `esxcli`, `vcli` or any other cli means.

I couldn't find an `esxcli` command, which is expected as its scope is primarily the host.

I installed `vcli` on a Windows 7 system and tried [`vmware-cmd`](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc%2Fcli_manage_vms.10.7.html) but it has another function (connect/disconnect) and I even couldn't make that work.

I haven't tried [`PowerCLI Cmdlets`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/VMGuestNetworkInterface.html) nor editing the `vmx` file directly (as this would have unexpected results on a running vm, I assume) yet.

I couldn't find any other [commands](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc%2Fcli_manage_vms.10.1.html) to perform this simple task.

I'm interested in solutions on both, Linux and Windows — or some Linux command that also runs on `cygwin` or similar.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @ewwhite, lab automation, to connect vm to different networks on different setups.

Comment: For now, the only thing I can think of, is powering-off the VM, writing the new network label on the `vmx` file and restarting it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you have not tried using PowerCLI, that would be the easiest and fastest way to do that. You can change the network adapter from connected to disconnected, change the network label (vLAN), or remove it all together. From all the times I have used this I have not come across any adverse effects on the VM's.

Comment: Let's say, that I'm more interested in a somewhat platform-independent solution — or rather, something that would run on *nix, that I could also run on Windows via cygwin.